# How grip files based on words from a file?

Tags: r

I have this text file:

```
 l=c("ced","nad")
 h=c("SAF","EYR")
 res=cbind(l,h)
```

and this list of files:

```
 dirf<- list.files ("path", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

example of files

```
 ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt
 ced_EYR_jkh_2001.txt
 nad_SAF_jkh_200.txt
 nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt
```

I want to grip files that contain both words in the two columns, so the files i need

```
 ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt
 nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the name from the matrix and use that, i.e.

```
do.call(paste, c(data.frame(res), sep = '_'))
#[1] "ced_SAF" "nad_EYR"
```

To grep them you can do,

```
ptrn <- do.call(paste, c(data.frame(res), sep = '_'))

grep(paste(ptrn, collapse = '|'), x, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt" "nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt"
```

where `x`,

```
dput(x)
c("ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt", "ced_EYR_jkh_2001.txt", "nad_SAF_jkh_200.txt", 
"nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt")
```

Comment: thanks but how to grep that from list of files?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

l=c("ced","nad")
h=c("SAF","EYR")
res=cbind(l,h)

df <- data.frame(
  files = c("ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt","ced_EYR_jkh_2001.txt","nad_SAF_jkh_200.txt",
            "nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt")
)

df %>% 
  filter((str_detect(files, res[1,1]) & str_detect(files, res[1,2])) | 
  (str_detect(files, res[2,1]) & str_detect(files, res[2,2])))

#>                  files
#> 1 ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt
#> 2  nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt
```

---

Or, more compactly, with `purrr::map2_dfr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2_dfr(res[,1], res[,2],
         ~ filter(df, (str_detect(files, .x) & str_detect(files, .y))))

#>                  files
#> 1 ced_SAF_jkh_2020.txt
#> 2  nad_EYR_jkh_200.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf()` + `paste(collapse = '|')` to make the expected syntax of *regular expression* and pass it to `list.files()` directly:

```
regex <- paste(sprintf("%s_%s", l, h), collapse = '|')
# [1] "ced_SAF|nad_EYR"
```

```
list.files("path_to_file", regex, full.names = TRUE)
```

Then all the file names which match the regular expression will be returned.